# Django pdf: page layout with long texts using pisa

Tags: django, pisa

I use pisa to generate some PDF files of the following layout:

```
  @page {
        size: a4;
        @frame header {
          top: 5.4cm;
          bottom: 4cm;
          left: 1.2cm;
          right: 1.2cm;
        }
        @frame main {
          top: 10.5cm;
          bottom: 4cm;
          left: 1.2cm;
          right: 1.2cm;
        }
        @frame footer {
          top: 26cm;
          left: 1.2cm;
          right: 1.2cm;
        }
      }
```

Sometimes the content of the main frame is not short enough to fit in a single page and so it uses the space of the footer frame as well. Instead of that, I would like to have the rest of the text in the main's frame space of the second page (and keep the space of the rest frames clear). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

Pisa is not particularly easy to figure out. I use it to generate several different formats of reports.

I do not put my main content within a frame. Also it's all in inches/letter sized, but I want to give you exactly how mine is setup, and works for multiple pages.

Your problem may be fixed by adding margin to the `@page` or `<keepinframe></keepinframe>`
tags.

```
<document pagesize='letter'>
<head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @page {
            size: letter portrait;
            margin: 1.0in 0.25in 0.5in 0.25in;
            padding: 0;

            @frame header {
                -pdf-frame-content: headerContent;
                width: 8in;
                top: 0.5in;
                margin-left: 0.5in;
                margin-right: 0.5in;
                height: 1.0in;
            }
            @frame footer {
                -pdf-frame-content: footerContent;
                width: 8in;
                bottom: 0in;
                margin-left: 2cm;
                margin-right: 2cm;
                height: 1cm;
            }
        } <!-- end of @page bracket -->

        <!-- add content styles here -->
        h1 { text-align: middle; font-size: 18px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='headerContent'>
    <!-- header content -->
</div>
<div>
    <keepinframe>
     <!-- Content -->
    </keepinframe>
</div>
<div id='footerContent'>
    <!-- footer content -->
    <pdf:pagenumber>
</div>
</body>
</document>
```

Comment: you are right that it is not easy to figure out, after 6 years that is still the case!!! Anyways, i have been running into an issue, might you have any ideas? Question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45534895/720508