# How to set the width of the page?

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab, xhtml2pdf, pisa

I have been trying to increase the width of pdf but nothing seems to work:

```
<style type="text/css">
@page {
    size: a4 landscape;
    width: 27cm;  /* not working */
    @frame content {
        top: 2cm;
        width: 27cm;  /* not working */
        margin-left: 1.5cm;  /* changing these values work!! */
        margin-bottom: 2cm;  /* changing these values work!! */
    }
}
</style>
```

No matter what I try, the content width doesn't seem to increase. All my `<div>`, `<tables>` are at 100%, and reducing the margin increases the size of the table, so the 100% is probably working. But how to increase the width of the main container? From what I can deduce, it looks like it is keeping to some default width, and it does not increase, because both `portrait` and `landscape` result in the same width content.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: You might want to look at the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961365/django-easy-pdf-header-on-every-page-of-the-document#41975542. They use a different package but it might give you some insight on what is wrong.